# Can i write Cocoa Touch[iPhone] applications in C++ language

Tags: iphone, c++

1) Can i write iPhone applications in pure C++ language, i know that we can use Objective-C++, i just want to know if we can also write it in pure C++ language.

2) while creating MAC OX application inXCode, we have an option to create C/C++ application, will the same options work for me to write iPhone applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use pure C++ only - at least a portion of the UI must be written in Objective C/Objective C++, as all applications must provide a delegate and a main view.

Once you have the application running and do not wish to use the UI libraries (such as a game), you can proceed to use Core Graphics or OpenGL to handle screen drawing. You will need a small Objective C/C++ layer to handle touch events.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can u please send me a sample Objective-C++ helloworld program for iPhone application? since i'm a newbiee i'm very much confused. please help

Comment: Hi Yann, please reply.. its ok even if u don send me a sample program, jus tel me steps to create a Objective-C++ program for iPhoen application

Comment: @suse: Apple has great documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Comment: But the link says about creating a Objective-C program for iPhone app?  Is it all the same for Objective-C++ also ?

Comment: Are frameworks used for Objective-C and Objective-C++ same in iPhone programming ?

Comment: The "Objective" part of Objective-C and Objective-C++ is identical.