# How can i create an UITableView on Xcode 4.2,for IOS 5?

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode, uitableview, ios5

Last week i have downloaded Xcode 4.2, so when i started building apps i've tried to add an `UITableView` to one of my projects (as normal as i have been doing since i began developing) but the `UITableView` isn't working. I've searching for tutorials but i didn't found any so:
    How can i create an UITableView on Xcode 4.2,for IOS 5?

obs:I'm not using storyBoard just the XIB's!

Comment: "the UITableView isn't working"  .... *What's* not working?

Comment: First when i just add the UITableView to my xib and build,i try to scroll the tableview and nothing happens!

Comment: Can you share some code?  Specifically, the tableview datasource and delegate callbacks?

Comment: Is better if i upload my project?So you can download.

Comment: My project is very simple!I've just started a new project and dropped an UITableView on the screen,so when i build and try to scroll the tableView nothing happen!

Comment: I've uploaded to megaupload (http://www.megaupload.com/?d=NS2WT5YV).But is what i said very simple!

Comment: Sounds like multiple reasons.... your dataset is empty and bounce is switched off, or the datasource and delegates havent been set etc. You need to post the table setting code and elaborate on your question by describing it in more detail :)

Comment: Your link is not working, btw.

Comment: Dropping a tableView on a view is not enough.  You have to set the datasource & delegate and implement the callback methods.  Have you ever done tableView coding on pre ios5?  I would recomment going through a UITableView tutorial - many on the net.  BTW, it works fine on ios5

Comment: There is a longer programming guide for UITableView at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html (with pictures)

Comment: Hey @Jack, we have a philosophy here at Stack Overflow that just because something can be found on Google, doesn't mean it's not a good question or shouldn't be asked. Search for "Google" on meta.stackoverflow.com to learn more about this policy, [for example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76195/how-to-deal-with-have-you-tried-google-comments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your .h file, add the following:

```
@interface YourClass: UIViewController <**UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate**>
```

right-click (or ctrl-click) and drag from your tableView to the File's Owner twice.  Once, select "delegate", and once select "dataSource".

Then, in your .m file, you need to implement the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{return someNumber;}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:yourText];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //do what you want to with the information at indexPath.row
}
```

That should get you a working tableView.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the project template "Master-Detail Application" and look at the mechanisms to create your own code in C++.

But at the core, creating a UITableView is a two step:

- init the view
- plug it to its delegate/datasource

also, this might help you: [Can i write Cocoa Touch[iPhone] applications in C++ language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130895/can-i-write-cocoa-touchiphone-applications-in-c-language)