# How to retrieve values from entire column to NSArray or NSMutableArray in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am new to Objective-C. I have created a single view application that stores and retrieves values from sqlite database. However I am able understand how to store entire column data from sqlite database to NSArray or NSMutableArray. I know the SQL statement that I need to write. Please guide me on how to replace this statement with `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` pointer?

```
NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
```

Comment: "However I am able understand" - do you mean you are **not** able to understand? Else I don't see the point.

Comment: I think you can find something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149368/how-to-display-data-from-sqlite-into-table-views-to-iphone-app
Especially second answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into FMDB.  It's an objective-c wrapper around SQLite that allows you to access a SQLite database easily from objective-c.  It avoids the hassle of having to access the SQLite database in straight c.  This should help you set/retrieve the values from the database.

You can find the code for FMDB here:
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb