# Cells not appearing in tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have got an history page, which is a UItableview with 5 rows.  I have set the prototype cell to the specs i want, and added this text to the corresponding historyviewcontroller.h file:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath           *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HistoryItem"];
return cell;
}
```

I am not seeing any cells when i run the app.  I've clearly missed something, but i can't quite see what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually create the cells.  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier only retrieves already created cells and does not create new ones.

Here's how to do it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath           *)indexPath
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HistoryItem"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //if cell is not nil, it means it was already created and correctly dequeued.
    if (cell == nil) {
        //create, via alloc init, your cell here
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I have been placing this in my HistoryViewController.m, is this the correct place?  My history view is presented when someone taps the history button (located on the main view).

Comment: Also, i used the code from above, and i had various errors.  To be error free i had to edit to this: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HistoryItem"];
    //if cell is not nil, it means it was already created and correctly dequeued.
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        //create, via alloc init, your cell here
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"HistoryItem"];
    }
   
return cell;
}

Comment: Well ive found another SO link which solved my issue.  I should have looked harder before creating a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910206/how-can-i-create-an-uitableview-on-xcode-4-2-for-ios-5

Comment: As of iOS 5, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is guaranteed to return a cell. So the if statement (and everything inside) is not required under iOS 5 and onwards.

Comment: Thanks for the info Robotic Cat.  Its always useful to know, as i find a lot of the answers are filled with older code, which is sometimes "old hat".